# Computer Won't Turn On And Power Goes Out

Tags: power-supply, power

When I plug in my computer and click the switch on the PSU and then the power goes out (It's the house power)

How would I check if the PSU is faulty?

The computer I have is a computer that I put together myself.

Comment: I can't think of anything it could be other than a bad PSU.  If the problem was beyond the PSU, the PSU would overload before the house breaker.  The computer "on" button is actually a signal line; it doesn't handle wall voltage.  If you are talking about a PSU with a built-in power switch, there could be a short inside the PSU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if you're saying that your computer's power is going out or if your house's fuse is shorted and thus power goes out in the house/appartment.

In both cases I would say a faulty PSU is a possibility.
In case of the latter it might also be a faulty socket/fuse or even a faulty power cord so try connecting it to a completely different socket that is wired to a different fuse (if you are not sure, go to a completely different room, as far away from the original room as possible) and if you have one at your disposal, use a different power cord.

In any case: try using different sockets first. If that doesn't help you should get a different PSU to try if that solves your issue.

Comment: +1, bad assembly and OP has grounded a PSU rail or the PSU has failed.

Comment: It's the house power, how would I check if the PSU is faulty

Comment: @GhostCyborg I've added that info to your question.